# Choose whether to save when quit

Tags: notepad++

I am using notepad++ V6.4.2. When I close a file, it seems to save defaultly without asking me. How can I configure to get the save/not_save option back?

Comment: NP+++ doesn't have an auto-save option AFAIK (they do have a backup system, but that's not the same as what you're explaining).  There ARE a few plugins that will do auto-saves.  Have you ensured you don't have a plugin installed/enabled that's doing it?

Comment: @yliueagle: You might want to update Notepad++ to the latest version as it is at v6.6.7 now. The version I have does show the behaviour you have described but I was able to change it using the method I have given in my answer.

Comment: @James Thanks. I updated to the new version and get what I want.

Answer (score 10):

Notepad++ isn't actually saving the file automatically. If you open the file in another editor you will see that your changes have not been committed to the original file. It is using its own temporary copy of the file to hold the changes that have been made.

However, you can prevent Notepad++ from behaving this way by un-checking **Settings->Preferences->Backup->Enable session snapshot and periodic backup**.

**Edit:** As Rob has pointed out, this applies to version 6.6 and later where this feature is turned on by default and doesn't require add-ons.

[image]

Comment: I thought this too, but apparently that was only enabled in 6.6 ( http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.6-release.html ) and he's running 6.4

Answer (score 0):

In Settings->Preferences->Backup->
I "disabled session snapshots" and now it ask me when I close notepad++ if I want to save the file changes.

Answer (score -1):

Deselect the option "Remember current session for next launch" will work as in Notepad.

Comment: Session management and File Save management are independent. If I have "Remember current session for next launch" enabled or disabled I'm still prompted to save modified files when closing