# Any way to have Notepad++ automatically save on exit?

Tags: notepad++, autosave

Is there any way I can get Notepad++ to save and close under one command?

For example on hitting Alt-F4, Notepad++ would not only close the program, but also save the document.

(manually editing a very large number of txt documents, and want to avoid having any additional number of key strokes)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose whether to save when quit](http://superuser.com/questions/781854/choose-whether-to-save-when-quit)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 no duplicate - that q. is doesn't address how to auto-save on exit (that question asker incorrectly assumed notepadd++ was set to save automatically, which isn't the case)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+S (File/Save All) then Alt+F4 is only 3 extra keystrokes and could be put in a macro very easily ...

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a plugin to do exactly what you want, but there is one to auto save open documents which may be an easy alternative.

It's called AutoSave and is available to download [here](https://sites.google.com/site/fstellari/nppplugins).

It's configurable to save all or just current file at a user-defined interval along with offering some over-write options.

More information about it is available [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/bring-auto-save-feature-to-notepad-with-autosave-plugin/).

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't help in my instance - I will be making minor edits to txt files which take just 1 or 2 seconds to do... looking to always save changes on exit. (task will be repeated by someone approx 100,000 times) The plugin mentioned only allows option to save in minute intervals. (i.e. autosaving every 1min is most frequent will do)

Comment: @kyrenia, at least from v1.20 ( 2010-07-16) Franco Stellaris Autosave plugin now handles autosave on loss of focus.